# Get data from inner page and merge with current page

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

in my html page there is table with two columns, the first one name and the second one a Link in which there is a **date**, i want to be able to download this page get this **date** and raise it, so in the output i will have Name and Date.
For example
in the first page we have

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>A</td>
         <td>http://something.com/2564.html</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

in the 2564.html page there is

```
<body>
     <p>the date is: 25 April 2009</p>
</body>
```

how can i have

```
<xml>
     <row>
         <name>A</name>
         <date>25 April 2009</date>
     </row>
</xml>
```

Comment: When you load this page do you get all the DOM elements you need. If the answer is yes you can use sgml parser and I will share some sample code with you

Answer (score 0):

My approach it to create the item, fill it with the data i have on this page, then yield a request for the page with missing data, passing the item within `meta`. When the second page is downloaded i get the item from `meta` and fill with the other data:

```
def parseItem(self, response):
    '''Get date from the first page.'''
    item = Item()
    item['firstdata'] = '???'
    ...
    otherDataPageLink = '???'
    yield Request(otherDataPageLink, meta = {'item': item}, callback = self.parseComments)

def parseComments(self, response):
    '''Get all the other data from second page.'''
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['otherdata'] = '???'
    yield item # return the item with all the data
```